# How can I synchronize both movement and an animation using cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, synchronization

I need help getting a CCSprite to animate and move in a synchronized fashion repeatedly. For example I need to move the sprite from one game board space to the next while walking. While I can call each action right after one another, I have found that when run in rapid succession the two don't fire at the same time causing either an additional animation cycle to run between moves or movements to not be aligned with the start/end of the animation.

Here are examples of how I'm creating the animation and movement actions.

```
CCAnimation *animRunUR_ = [CCAnimation animationWithFrame:@"actor_run_ur" frameCount:8 delay:runAnimDuration_];
CCAction *_actionAnimRunUR = [[CCSequence actions:
                     [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animRunUR_],
                     [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animationFinished)],
                     nil] retain];

CCAction *_action = [[CCSequence actions:
                     [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:duration_ position:gridbox_.center],
                     [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(nextMovement)],
                   nil] retain];
```

Each of the above actions are called directly on the CCSprite as follows.

```
[self.sprite runAction:_action];
[self.sprite runAction:_actionAnimRunUR];
```

The duration of the animation is calculated to be equal to the amount of time it takes to move to the next game board space. In addition, these are fairly straight forward actions but I'm really having a hard time keeping them synced as they continually repeat.

Any best practices or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure this is a common issue in game development with sprites that continually animate while moving. Then trying to keep smooth transitions between things like walk, run, and jump without split second pauses between actions. Thanks for your feedback and suggestions.

Comment: do runAnimDuration_ and duration_ have the same value?

Comment: They are calculated based on the sprites speed and are almost identical. When I log them, they are runAnimDuration = 0.475829f and duration_ = 0.475828f.

Comment: why don't you use the same variable for both?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I could do that, just didn't since they aren't in the same class. Anyway I figured out what was happening. Everything works as you'd expect as long as you start them consecutively and the durations are equal. My issue was that I had an additional method that was causing an additional call to be made to the animate method on my sprite causing the mis-sync and additional animation call. Still amazing to me how I can miss the forest for the trees sometimes. Thanks again! :0)